# Unable to map path to postresql after installation of Postgres 9.3 to mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

After installing Postgresql by dragging folder into my applications folder I am unable to get commands to work in the terminal and unable to add the path so that is shows up using the command $ echo $PATH.

Postgres starts in the terminal using the elephant icon on the system tray and selecting "open psql" so I believe it installed correctly.

I tried adding all different combinations of the following lines to my .bash_profile

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

and finally

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

after each attempt I ran $ source $HOME/.bash_profile and then checked path and/or tried $psql $ which psql to no avail.

Also tried adding lines to .bashrc , .profile and .zshrc without luck.

The path to the executable commands bin folder in the app (psql, createdb, createlang, etc..) is

```
$ /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

running OSX 10.9.1

Comment: What does which psql return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/707222/unable-to-get-postgresql-commands-to-work-in-terminal

answered at the link above by zelanix https://superuser.com/users/293259/zelanix